# UnicodeDecodeError in python 3.5 when trying to open text files

Tags: python

I am trying to open some configuration files with following command:

```
f=open(os.path.join(root, name),mode='rt',errors='ignore')
```

However, I am getting the following error after upgrading to python 3.5.

---

```
for line in f:
  File "C:\python35-32\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x90 in position 57: chara
cter maps to <undefined>
```

---

This code worked fine when, I ran using python 2.7. I have tried to specify encoding as utf8 or latin1 but none of them are working now. It would be very much helpful if anyone can suggest me a way forward?

It will be ok if I can ignore the error and go to the next line. How can I skip the erroneous part?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with python 3. I think your opening a file with 8-bit encoding (e. g. latin1) , and the interpreter tries utf-8. You should check the bytes at position 57. Could you append a hex dump of the surrounding block (just a few bytes)?

Answer (score 1):

Try to specify encoding of file `open(os.path.join(root, name), encoding='utf-8')`

Comment: Tried that already & getting the following error:for line in f:
  File "C:\python35-32\lib\codecs.py", line 321, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x82 in position 10: invalid
 start byte

Comment: So the file has an encoding different from utf-8.

Comment: @ Sergey: Seems like that but what can be the way forward?

Comment: What format of the file? From where you get this file?

Comment: Its ".cfg" file. Configuration file of routers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use codecs.open

```
import codecs
f = codecs.open(os.path.join(root, name), mode='rt', encoding='utf-8')
for line in f:
    #do something
```

Also, I don't think the problem is with your code but rather with Windows command prompt as its encoding is 'cp1252'. I'd run into this issue long back. Basically, if you run your script on Windows command prompt and as soon as your code executes the print function (to print the unicode data) the program would crash since Windows command prompt is unable to decode and print it.

You can also get around this problem by printing the raw data. That is, change all print function to `print("%r" % line)`

Comment: Tried with codecs & getting following error: for line in f:
  File "C:\python35-32\lib\codecs.py", line 711, in __next__
    return next(self.reader)
  File "C:\python35-32\lib\codecs.py", line 642, in __next__
    line = self.readline()
  File "C:\python35-32\lib\codecs.py", line 555, in readline
    data = self.read(readsize, firstline=True)
  File "C:\python35-32\lib\codecs.py", line 501, in read
    newchars, decodedbytes = self.decode(data, self.errors)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode bytes in position 14-15: invalid
continuation byte

Comment: Well, then your file encoding must be something else. Open the file, do "Save As" and change encoding to 'UTF-8' (Without BOM) then try your code.